# What do Americans call the fuel in a gas-powered car?

Tags: american-english

In Britain the usual fuel for cars is *petrol*, but some cars are converted to use *gas*, by which is meant *natural gas*.

But in America the word *gas* is already taken (meaning *petrol*). So what does an American with a gas-powered car ask for when refuelling in a...er...gas station?

(I see a selection of TLAs are defined at the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_gas_vehicle); are any of these in common use?)

Comment: In Britain we usually call it "LPG", don't we?

Comment: @WS2, I'm not sure, but the new buses in Darlington run on _gas_ (I haven't heard anyone call it LPG).

Comment: There are apparently 40,000 vehicles on the UK "LPG Register". But you are right, I have heard it referred to simply as *gas*. And that makes it confusing if talking to Americans.

Comment: Not all gas powered vehicles run on propane or butane.  Reading Buses have a world-record holding biomethane-powered bus, as well as oher dual-fuel and LPG powered buses.
 http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-berkshire-32801974

Comment: *Natural gas* to an American like me signifies methane; propane is different and larger molecule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of different gases that can be used to power vehicles in the U.S., and none is especially common at the consumer level. They are by and large the stuff of commercial and government fleets and a few alternative fuel enthusiasts.

As such, there is no generic term for all vehicles powered by gaseous fuels, and **no generic term** for all gaseous fuels. You need to specify *which* gas, and sometimes which form of the gas is in use.

---

Based on some of the other answers given, perhaps we should start by defining *natural gas*. In North America, this term applies exclusively to a blend of fuel gases dominated by methane. NaturalGas.org, a site sponsored by the Natural Gas Supply Association (an industry group of producers and distributors), provides this [typical composition of refined natural gas](http://naturalgas.org/overview/background/):

> Methane   70-90%
>   Ethane, propane, and butane 0-20%
>   Carbon dioxide      0-8%
>   Oxygen  0-0.2%
>   Nitrogen    0-5%
>   Hydrogen sulphide   0-5%
>   Rare gases  trace

If you were to say you drove a *natural gas vehicle* (or that your vehicle had a *natural gas engine* or was *natural gas-fueled*), the assumption is that your fuel is indeed methane-based ***natural gas***. *Biogas* (*biomethane*, *[renewable natural gas/RNG](http://www.afdc.energy.gov/fuels/natural_gas_renewable.html)*) refers to the sourcing of the gas as opposed to its composition or properties, so referring to a vehicle as a *biogas* vehicle is an exercise in ego, as opposed to engineering.

The most commonly distributed format is *compressed natural gas*, or *CNG*; *liquefied natural gas* or *LNG* is still rare. I have found *CNG* in [consumer magazines](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/2012/03/the-natural-gas-alternative/index.htm), but the average person may or may not understand the distinction between the two, or between them and uncompressed natural gas (as for example delivered to homes for heating and cooking). Those in the transportation or energy industries may be more familiar.

---

The next most popular alternative vehicle fuel [as of 2009](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2013/05/26/the-most-common-alternative-fuel-may-surprise-yo.aspx) is liquefied petroleum gas, ***LPG***, which is a blend dominated by propane and thus commonly referred to simply as ***propane***. This gas is a common heating, cooking, and lighting fuel in rural areas and in camping equipment, and to the lay person, a *propane* engine or device is one that runs on LPG, as opposed to *propane* in the strict sense of the chemical compound, for example in the catchphrase of Hank Hill on the sitcom *King of the Hill*: *[I sell propane and propane accessories.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-sell-propane-and-propane-accessories)*

The term *autogas* for LP gas does not seem to be widespread; note, for example, the [absence of *autogas engine*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=LPG%20engine%2Cautogas%20engine%2Cpropane%20engine&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3) in Google NGrams against *LPG engine* and *propane engine*, which are themselves [rare against *diesel engine* and *gasoline engine*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=LPG%20engine%2Cautogas%20engine%2Cpropane%20engine%2Cgasoline%20engine%2C%20diesel%20engine&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3). The only place it turns up on the U.S. Energy Information Administration website is in a description of natural gas liquids: "[a popular fuel in some parts of Europe, Turkey, and Australia](https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.cfm?id=5930)."

---

The fuel for hydrogen engines, whether internal combustion or fuel cell, is simply *hydrogen*, and more than appropriate as unlike the other gases, it is not a blend of consumables. But hydrogen vehicles are barely more than a [laboratory curiosity](http://www.afdc.energy.gov/fuels/hydrogen_locations.html).

Answer (score 2):

The terms used to refer to  ***[LPG](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/LPG)*** are ***propane and autogas:***

> - liquefied petroleum gas
> - (Elements & Compounds) a mixture of various petroleum gases, esp propane and butane, stored as a liquid under pressure and used as an engine fuel.

(AHD)

***[Propane vehicles](http://www.afdc.energy.gov/vehicles/propane.html):***

> - ***Propane, also known as liquefied petroleum gas (LPG), or autogas***, is considered an alternative fuel under the [Energy Policy Act of 1992](http://www.afdc.energy.gov/laws/key_legislation#epact92). According to the Propane Education and Research Council, there are more than 143,000 on-road propane vehicles in the United States. Many are used in fleet applications, such as school buses, shuttles, and police vehicles.

(Alternative Fuels Data Centre - US)

Comment: Propane is not the same thing as natural gas. Different substance, different infrastructure, different technologies.

Comment: @choster - I am not  an expert, but the surce appears to be reliable.

Comment: I may have misuderstood, but isn't OP asking about LPG fuelled cars?

Comment: OP asked about *natural gas* as used in the U.S. and in the Wikipedia article. Propane would no sooner be referred to as natural gas in the U.S. than kerosene as diesel, but perhaps this distinction is not so strong elsewhere.

Comment: autogas is just a shortened form of "automobile gasoline" to differ it from "aviation gasoline" aka avgas.

Comment: @Skooba No. *Auto gas* is *automobile gasoline*. *[Autogas](http://www.autogasforamerica.org/why-autogas/the-basics)* is another name for *LPG* when use to power road vehicles.